# Android Activity recreating white screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I develop an app with a start `splashscreen activity` and a `main activity`.

If the app starts normal the `splashscreen` is shown and then the `main activity` with the `viewpager` inside is there.

But if the system killed the app in the background and the user start the app with the app icon, the `splashscreen` is shown (thats ok) and then there is a white page, some seconds ago the activity is rendered.

The white screen is very ugly.

Any idea what i can do that the white screen isn't show?
**Edit:**
Second Question: When is the activity rendering in the lifecycle?

Comment: code man share the code

Comment: show code and avoid splash-screens

Comment: Sorry i cant share the code.

Comment: I think this is the problem you're facing http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/

Comment: I found out, that the white screen appears if i have many fragments in my ViewPager. I use the FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Which methods are called when the activity is recreated?